# SonarQube MSBuild scanner stopping after pre-processing

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I'm trying to get SonarQube setup on our tfs build server and it keeps stopping the scan after pre-processing succeeds. I'm using the `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe`. There are no error messages at all. No indication that anything has gone wrong. I'm not sure where to go from here. Halp?

[image: cmd-screenshot]

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You need to build now, then run post processing.

Comment: I guess I was expecting it to work the same way as the `sonar-scanner.bat` does. I was expecting the scan to continue and to see some data in my SonarQube server. I wasn't aware that this is not how it works.

Comment: Ah! The new analyze runs as part of the build. See: http://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/6954824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in what you see as the output. You are just missing some bits and pieces.

> The “begin” invocation sets up the SonarQube analysis. Mandatory
>   analysis settings such as the SonarQube project key, name and version
>   must be passed in, as well as any optional settings, such as paths to
>   code coverage reports. During this phase, the scanner fetches the
>   quality profile and settings to be used from the SonarQube server.
>
> Then, you build your project as you would typically do. As the build
>   happens, the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild gathers the exact set of 
>   projects and source files being compiled and analyzes them.
>
> Finally, during the “end” invocation, remaining analysis data such as
>   Git or TFVC one is gathered, and the overall results are sent to the
>   SonarQube server.

[Source](http://www.sonarqube.org/easy-analysis-of-visual-studio-solutions-with-the-sonarqube-scanner-for-msbuild/)

In short, after the first command call (begin), you need to run [MSBuild 14.0](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMSBuild-msbuildcompatWithVisualStudioandMSBuild) and build your solution, then finish up the invocation (end) and see the analysis results in your SonarQube server, if everything went all right.

```
# This is part of the pre-build script
> MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:project_key /n:project_name /v:project_version

# Build your solution here
> msbuild /t:rebuild

# This is part of the post-build script
> MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

That small script should be part of your build pipeline (using Jenkins, TeamCity, or whatever CI tool) ideally.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This does help. I didn't realize I had to add the build step in there. I have it working now.

Comment: @TehBeardedOne Glad this clarified your question! Could you please mark this as an answer then? Cheers!